# Two overloading functions for the same operator and class

Tags: c++, class, sorting, overloading, operator-keyword

I want to use a sorting algorithm to sort my `vector` of clients, but the problem is I have two different criteria to sort them.

To display them to the screen and to save them into a file I need to sort them by ID, but to use it for some other stuff (like knowing the top ten worst clients) I need to sort them by the sum of money they've spent.

These are the overloading functions of the `operator==` for the client class, but obviously they can't co-exist. Can someone give me a solution for this?

```
    class Client
    {
    public:
    //...
        unsigned int getID() const;
        double getSum() const;
    //...
    private:
        unsigned int ID;
        //...
        double sum;
    };

    bool operator==(const Client &LHS, const Client &RHS)
    {
        return (LHS.getID() == RHS.getID());
    }

    bool operator==(const Client &LHS, const Client &RHS)
    {
        return (LHS.getSum() == RHS.getSum());
    }
```

Comment: Make them named member functions?

Comment: You can sort with an explicit comparator.

Comment: The operator== was just an example, obviously the sorting algorithm will also use the others (< and >)

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry, I'm a beginner, I have no idea what that is or how to use it. Can you post a solution or a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function overloads takes a comparator, use that form and provide it with two independent functions or functors (or lambdas) for each instantiation.

```
class Client
{
public:
    //...
    unsigned int getID() const;
    double getSum() const;
    //...
private:
    unsigned int ID;
    //...
    double sum;
};

bool CompareByID(const Client &LHS, const Client &RHS)
{
    return (LHS.getID() < RHS.getID());
}

bool CompareBySum(const Client &LHS, const Client &RHS)
{
    return (LHS.getSum() < RHS.getSum());
}

// ...
std::sort(container.begin(), container.end(), CompareByID);
```

*Note* the sort requires a comparison that obeys its ordering requirements, usually it uses a *less than* comparison to order the elements. The exact comparison can be different, but needs to obey the same ordering requirements (for further reading, see the information for the `std::sort` algorithm, and [this on](https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/05/strict-weak-ordering-and-stl) *strict weak ordering*).

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't believe I didn't think of that!

Comment: You certainly can't use those functions as predicates for `std::sort`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley. Damn. Didn't update the internal comparison, now updated.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes, you can! I've just tested it!

Comment: @DanielMarques: No you can't. It will compile, but it will not sort properly. It fails both on irreflexivity, and antisymmetry, which are requirements of the predicate function.

Comment: @Niall Is there a better sorting algorithm that can also take a predicate as an argument?

Comment: @DanielMarques. I'm not sure what you mean by better. Generally the standard library implementations are very efficient, but if you require something else or better suited to your environment, given the documentation for the algorithm you desire, it may be accompanied by a reference implementation. As always, measure before deciding.

Comment: @Niall Thanks! I was just guessing if std::sort was as good or the same as quicksort

Comment: @daniel. It is probably better. I'd don't have a reference at hand, but I believe most of the major implementations have some sort of a hybrid implementation that does better than the quick sort.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you could use std:sort algorithm.
You need to create 2 function each for sum and Id comparison and pass them as function pointer for comparison.

```
bool compare_by_ID(const Client &LHS, const Client &RHS)
{
        return (LHS.getID() < RHS.getID());
}


bool compare_by_sum(const Client &LHS, const Client &RHS)
{
        return (LHS.getSum() < RHS.getSum());
}
```

and to use them you need to invoke sort in this way

```
vector<Client> v;  
// assume v contains list of clients.

// for comparison by sum
std:sort(v.begin(),v.end(),compare_by_sum);

// for comparison by Id
std:sort(v.begin(),v.end(),compare_by_ID);
```

Apart from comparison function you could use more sophisticated approach by using functors or function objects.

Comment: Is there a better sorting algorithm that can also take a predicate as an argument?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on operator< to do your sorting, you can explicitly pass a comparator to std::sort:

```
std::vector<Client> vec;
...
auto sortByID = [](auto lhs, auto rhs){ return lhs.getID() < rhs.getID(); };
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), sortByID);
//vec is now sorted by ID

auto sortBySum = [](auto lhs, auto rhs){ return lhs.getSum() < rhs.getSum(); }
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), sortBySum);
//vec is now sorted by Sum
```